# Intermittent issue of HttpAntiForgeryException on Production only

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, csrf, antiforgerytoken

I am getting AntiForgery error on Production server intermittently.
Details:-

- Issue occurred on login page only, After reload it works
- Issue is intermittent
- Form authentication is used and site is deployed on single server.

> System.Web.Mvc.HttpAntiForgeryException (0x80004005): The anti-forgery
>    cookie token and form field token do not match.
>   **Steps to produce:-**
>   * Logged in to site
>   * Leave it open for long or close the browse
>   * Open the login page again after 1-2 hour.. 
>   you may get this error of anti forgery token "*The anti-forgery
>    cookie token and form field token do not match."* 
>   But its not guaranteed that we encounter error. We get error only intermittently which gets resolved once user try to login again.

I tried so many option but could not resolve the issue.

Comment: Machine key is not configured, as site is deployed on Single server

Answer (score 1):

the reason for this error can be
 1. you have setup the server at a new location or
 2. you have reset the IIS while the application is still in use for some client (because on reset it generates a new token for that session)

Comment: Issue occurring on production site, app pool is not recycled in that duration.. its intermittent.. Logged in to site close the browser and open the login page again after 1-2 hour.. you may get this error of anti forgery.. But its not guaranteed that you will get the error

Comment: @ashishmishra did you check event logs to verify that?  You may not have recycling configured but an unhandled exception will cause one. Another possibility is AV is causing a file to been seen as modified, causing a recycle.

Comment: @Andy: Login post action is decorated by Antiforgery attribute and I checked log on server but as per the logs,even  first line of login action was not executed and in log getting Antiforgery exception. It means our login method is not culprit. As per the logs action login(post) was called. I will try to check the event logs also on server. One more thing.. each piece of code is wrapped in try catch block and logger in catch block so if exception occurred any where it will be logged.

Comment: what is the authentication token age for accessing the API?
I think it is getting expired and it is giving this exception.
try to add logs on token middleware .

Comment: Authentication token is cookie.its cookie and hidden field in form validated at server. its age is Session. so it is valid till browser is open.